# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when updating notification

Tags: android, service, notifications, java.util.concurrent, foreground

I get this issue from firebase, from a moto g5, 100% in background android 8.1, im running a foreground service, here is the firebase stacktrace

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
   at android.util.ArrayMap.put(ArrayMap.java:523)
   at android.os.Bundle.putParcelable(Bundle.java:501)
   at android.app.Notification.addFieldsFromContext(Notification.java:2440)
   at android.app.Notification.addFieldsFromContext(Notification.java:2433)
   at android.app.Notification$Builder.build(Notification.java:4974)
   at com.apep.burnedcalories.CountUpTimerService.updateNotification(CountUpTimerService.java:445)
   at com.apep.burnedcalories.CountUpTimerService.access$updateNotification(CountUpTimerService.java:43)
   at com.apep.burnedcalories.CountUpTimerService$onStartCommand$1.invokeSuspend(CountUpTimerService.kt:335)
   at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

this is the foreground service class onstartcomand method, here i call the updatenotification method every second to update the title because its a timer:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    CoroutineScope(job).launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            while (isBound) {
                if (!isBound) break
                if(timer_stoped == false){
                    startChronometer()
                    timeFlow.value = getTimestamp().also { time ->
                        if(start_exercise.txt_time2 != time) {
                            if(mets_i != intervalo_mets || peso != intervalo_peso){
                                intervalo = elapsedmilis
                                intervalo_kcal = burnedcalories
                                intervalo_mets = mets_i
                                intervalo_peso = peso
                            }
                            burnedcalories = intervalo_kcal + (((0.0175 / 60) * mets_i * peso)*((elapsedmilis-intervalo)/1000))
                            burnedfat = (burnedcalories / 7.7)
                            if(isguided == true){
                                if(progress < 100.0){
                                    if(tts_init == true){
                                        tts_init = false
                                        if (lang_supported == true) {
                                            speak_start(remaining_time)
                                        } else speak_start_en(remaining_time)
                                    }
                                    progress = ((burnedcalories-resume_kcal.toDouble())/start_exercise.goalkcal)*100
                                    remaining_time = getTimestamp2(((((start_exercise.goalkcal+resume_kcal.toDouble())- burnedcalories)/((0.0175/60)*start_exercise.mets_i*start_exercise.peso))*1000).toLong())
                                }else{
                                    progress = 100.0
                                    remaining_time = "00:00:00"
                                }
                                if(((100/numero_notis)*notis_done)<=progress.toInt()){
                                    if(numero_notis == notis_done){
                                        if (lang_supported == true) {
                                            speak_end()
                                        } else speak_end_en()
                                    }else{
                                        if (lang_supported == true) {
                                            speak_noti(burnedcalories.toInt().toString(), progress.toInt().toString())
                                            speak_start(remaining_time)
                                        } else{
                                            speak_noti_en(burnedcalories.toInt().toString(), progress.toInt().toString())
                                            speak_start_en(remaining_time)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    notis_done++
                                    val prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
                                    val editor = prefs.edit()
                                    editor.putString("burnedcalories", burnedcalories.toString())
                                    editor.putLong("elapsedmilis", elapsedmilis)
                                    editor.putInt("notis_done", notis_done)
                                    editor.apply()
                                }
                            }
                            start_exercise.txt_time2 = time
                            start_exercise.txt_time = time
                            updateNotification(time, start_exercise.burnedcalories.toInt().toString(), start_exercise.burnedfat.toInt().toString())
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    pauseChronometer()
                }
                delay(1000)
            }
    }

    return START_STICKY
}
```

This is the updatenotification method, here is where i get the exeption:

```
private fun updateNotification(timestamp: String, caloriasquemadas: String, grasaquemada: String) {
    val notificationManager =
        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        val notification = notificationBuilder
                .setContentTitle(timestamp)
                .setContentText(caloriasquemadas + "KCAL - " + grasaquemada + "G")
                .build()
        notificationManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
    }else{
        val notification = builder
                .setContentTitle(timestamp)
                .setContentText(caloriasquemadas + "KCAL - " + grasaquemada + "G")
                .build()
        notificationManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
    }
}
```

Comment: if `Service::onStartCommand` is called multiple times then it will create  a new `CoroutineScope` and launch from a thread from `Dispatchers.IO` which may of may not be two different threads - presumably it ends up updating the notification from different threads, whilst one is iterating over a map the other mutates it hence the error.  Not to mention having potentionlly having 2+ `SharedPreference.Editor` instances competing.  There is in fact multiple potential issues.  Any interaction with updating the notifcation should be down using `Dispatchers.Main` - but this is a hacky fix at best.

Comment: @Mark in other words what i need to do in the onstartcomand in my case that is a kind of timer?